# A good approach to trigger array filter as needed, so won't trigger the whole list of filter again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

I have a filter state, let's call it `filterState`, it would be updated base on the filter change, the filter state looks like this `filterState = {"resolved": true, type: "someString", "isTicketRequired": false}`

I need to use `filterState` to filter an array, let's call the array data, the data array looks like this

```
data = 
[
  {...some properties, resolve: true, type: "minor", isTicketRequired: false}, 
  {...some properties, resolve: false, type: "major", isTicketRequired: true}, 
  {...some properties, resolve: true, type: "medium", isTicketRequired: false}
]
```

So the code snippet I used to filter data is like this

```
const filterArray = Object.entries(filterState);
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filterArray.length; i++) {
      result = data.filter(
        (d) => d[filterArray[i][0]] === filterArray[i][1]
      );
    }
    return result;
```

This can work, however, once `filterState` updated, it has to run the whole loop again. My question is what is a good method to store previous filtered data, and once filterState updated, just update data as needed, for example if just the value of `resolved` from `true` update to `false`, then we just filter previous filtered data base on `resolved`, don't need to run the whole loop again. I feel like it can be solved by useEffect, but lack of ideas

Comment: Your filter isn't working anyway because each iteration of the loop returns and sets result regardless of the previous filters. You should be using a single `filter()` call with an `every()` or `some()` on the `Object.entries()`.

Comment: That being said, you will always need to filter again from the full array because elements that didn't pass the previous filter, may pass the updated state.

Comment: `filterState` will get updated with the values of existing properties or properties will also add/remove in `filterState` ?